# Status bar color changed when hiding action bar in android

Tags: android, styles, themes

Status bar color changed when hiding action bar in android. When I am hiding my action bar using below code. My action bar color changed to black and also changed progress dialog color to white

```
<activity
android:name=".OrderTrackingActivity"
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

My style file

```
<resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
            <item name="colorControlNormal" >@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

    </resources>
```

Comment: please share your **Theme.Design.NoActionBar** theme

Comment: show @style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar file.

Comment: what parent theme you are using for Theme.Design.NoActionBar?

Comment: @Ankita See the update

Answer (score 1):

make changes to your style.xml file like: and "android:statusBarColor" it requires min API level 21

```
<style name="AppTheme.NooActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">Your color code</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```